# Load existing Drupal site in Drupal Docker container

Tags: php, docker, drupal, docker-compose

I want to load an existing Drupal site with all his dependencies in a freshly installed Drupal environment. 
Most of the websites are based on Drupal 7.x and PHP 5.x.

I already created a environment using Docker (Drupal 8.x and PHP 7.x).
Now I want to load/test my existing sites in this environment but I have no idea how to achieve this.

The compose file is running fine. I have a drupal installation + MariaDB.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  drupal:
    image: jonasvbogaert/digipolis-migration:latest
    container_name: drupalenv
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./Desktop:/var/www/html/modules
      - ./Desktop:/var/www/html/profiles
      - ./Desktop:/var/www/html/themes
      - ./Desktop:/var/www/html/sites
    restart: always
    environment:
      DRUPAL_SITE_NAME: Drupal
      DRUPAL_USER: admin
      DRUPAL_PASS: admin
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadbenv
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3036:3036
    depends_on:
      - drupal
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_USER: drupal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
```

UPDATE 08/25:

I think I made a little progression on this, but now I encountered a new problem. 
I'm able to load the root of my website inside my docker container, but I'm not able to access it on localhost. Got a 403 error.

My folder with the docker-compose file has to be placed in the root directory of my websites.

Edited docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  drupal:
    image: jonasvbogaert/php-docker:${IMAGE_VERSION}
    container_name: drupalenv
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/html/
    restart: always
    environment:
      DRUPAL_SITE_NAME: Drupal
      DRUPAL_USER: admin
      DRUPAL_PASS: admin
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadbenv
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3036:3036
    depends_on:
      - drupal
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_USER: drupal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal
```

Comment: Assuming your docker container is set up correctly, simple put the same code base as your live site in your container, and try to export a database and import it locally.

Comment: So you mean in the volumes?

Comment: Yes, my docker-compose looks like this for the volumes part: `- ./src/docroot:/var/www/html`. Why are you mounting your whole desktop into your container?

Comment: No it was just to test some stuff. 
Will give it a try! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way could be as follow
as you have a fresh install of drupal you can use features module (https://www.drupal.org/project/features) to export your work/dependencies from your existing site. Then import feature into your current fresh intall of drupal